# Execute runnable jar file in node server is slow

Tags: node.js, performance, express, server, jar

I tried to execute a runnable jar file in node server. It take 3 times of time compare to executing this jar file in window cmd. It take me 1.459 sec in window cmd but 4.829 sec in node server. I export the jar file in eclipse using the option "Extract required libraries into generated file but it does not help. I tried to remove Logger and System.out.print but it do not help as well. Any other method to boost the speed? And why the speed difference is so huge?

This is the code I use to start child process

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {


    var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('java -jar /home/java/testinput.jar',
  function (error, stdout, stderr){

    res.send(stderr);
    if(error !== null){
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to start the child process

Comment: @JKK added the child process code